# Java Spring Rest Client Connection Reset Error

Tags: java, spring, rest, weblogic

I have implemented rest client to consume a rest webservice using below code,

```
Client client = Client.create();
client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter(USERNAME,PASSWORD)); 
WebResource webResource = client.resource(URL);
ClientResponse clientResponse = webResource.type("application/json").accept("application/json").post(ClientResponse.class, REQUEST);
```

But I am facing below error,

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:155)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.HTTPBasicAuthFilter.handle(HTTPBasicAuthFilter.java:105)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:570)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessageListenerAdapter.java:339)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:535)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:495)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:467)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:323)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:241)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1056)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1048)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:947)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.readv0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.readv(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:278)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:440)
    at weblogic.socket.NIOInputStream.readInternal(NIOInputStream.java:148)
    at weblogic.socket.NIOInputStream.read(NIOInputStream.java:90)
    at weblogic.socket.NIOInputStream.read(NIOInputStream.java:73)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at weblogic.net.http.MessageHeader.isHTTP(MessageHeader.java:310)
    at weblogic.net.http.MessageHeader.parseHeader(MessageHeader.java:232)
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:554)
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:688)
    at weblogic.net.http.SOAPHttpURLConnection.getInputStream(SOAPHttpURLConnection.java:41)
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:1545)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invoke(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:253)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:153)
    ... 17 more
```

But If I restart the server this issue is not appearing for some time and again it appears. Has anyone faced similar issue ? I don't get any proper solution when googled.

I am using Weblogic Server in client side and rest service is also deployed in remote weblogic server.

EDIT- When I tried with curl command in the same server where it is throwing this error, it is retrieving the results.

Answer (score 0):

Connection reset by peer" is the TCP/IP equivalent of slamming the phone back on the hook. It's more polite than merely not replying, leaving one hanging. But it's not the FIN-ACK expected of the truly polite TCP/IP converseur.

check [here](http://everything2.com/title/Connection+reset+by+peer)

Comment: but I see curl command is working without any issues, though from application it is throwing error.